# Replace array id in DOM from user input - Hangman Game JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I am making a hangman game for class and I have it mostly working so far, however I am unable to replace the user input if the char is correct, to the `_` space on the DOM.

For example: `_ _ _ _ _` becomes `m _ l a _` as the user enters in the keys. Currently, I have it showing above, but would like it to replace the blanks. Also remove the `,`'s. How can I do that?

[image]

HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Disney Hangman Game</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="assets/js/hangman.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" align="center">
            <h1>Disney Hangman!</h1>
            <h2>Guess the Disney movie below.</h2>

            <h3 id="userText"> </h3>
            <h3 id="display"> </h3>
            <h3>Number of guesses left: <span id="guesses"></span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Array of disney movies options //
var options = ["moana", "lion king", "finding nemo", "aladdin", "mulan", "jungle book", "frozen", "tarzan", "little mermaid", "big hero 6"];

// Randomly select word from array //
var randomPick = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];

// Split the word picked into letters array //
var word = randomPick.split([]);
console.log(word)

// Array that records user input
var userArray = [];

// Counts length of the word that is split
var length = word.length;
console.log(length)

// Display length of word in HTML
window.onload = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    word[i] = "_";
}
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = word;
}

// Number of guesses
var guesses = 15;

// Store users inputs into userArray 
document.onkeyup = function(input) {
    console.log(input)
    // var userInput = input.key;
    var userInput = (input.key).toLowerCase();

    //Record Countdown
            if (input.key) {
                guesses--;
                console.log(guesses)

                userArray.push(userInput);
                console.log(userArray)

                if (guesses === 0) {
                    alert("Game Over!")
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (userInput === word[i]) {
                    userArray.push(userInput);
                    console.log(userArray)
                }
            }

            if (userArray.length === word.length) {
                alert("you win!")
            }

    // Display guess in guesses HTML
    document.getElementById("userText").innerHTML = userArray;
    // Display guesses left in HTML
    document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML = guesses;
}
```

Comment: What do you need? In the question it seems that you want to change the id of each doom, to an specific user. Is this what you want?If not, explain better what you want.

Comment: I think the problem could be that you are setting `innerHTML` of the element to an array instead of a string, you can simply join the array and set the element HTML or text to that value, `element.innerHTML = userArray.join("")`

Comment: @MohamedEl-Sayed thank you for your advice! that did remove the ,'s

Comment: To replace `_` with valid characters, you can use something like `userArray = userArray.map(chr => word.includes(userInput) ? chr : "_");` before setting the DOM element text.